# Is it appropriate to remove biologically meaningless pairwise comparisons after Dunn test for a post-hoc(FDR) analysis for multiple comparisons?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I have four individual groups(A, B, C, & D)
Differences between the groups are being analyzed by the Kruskal-Wallis test followed by Dunn's test for multiple comparisons (dunnTest command in R). We are interested in A-C, B-C, C-D, and A-B comparisons. So I would like to focus on these 4 multiple comparisons rather than the 6 runs for multiple comparisons by the test. Is this an appropriate thing to do?
This question is a little bit similar to the below question but somewhat different;
[Is it appropriate to remove meaningless pairwise comparisons from a post-hoc analysis before correcting for multiple comparisons?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329217/is-it-appropriate-to-remove-meaningless-pairwise-comparisons-from-a-post-hoc-ana/568231#568231)

Comment: Sorry, can see you are new here and asked this on the prior linked question. The prior linked question IMO is a duplicate of this one. I think it would be more useful to ping Alexis in the chat to that prior question to more flesh out a mathematical response with an example. Once you get that you should be able to figure out how to calc whatever adjustment when using specific tests.

Comment: Ye. that was deleted by the editor, I think. So I uploaded my question here again. Please let me know if I need to do something more.